# Specify one Checkbox to make a selected Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The direction to the goal>
Use one checkbox only that has the class asdf that should be enable to select the row by changing the background color to yellow. The remaining of the checkbox (to the right side) shall NOT enable to change the background color to yellow.
   In a short summary, the second and the third checkbox should not do anything.

Obstacle>

> The problem that I'm facing is that don't know how to solve it.

If possible not to change the structure of the html because it is used today in production phase.

http://jsfiddle.net/oc1n1c49/2/

Thank you!

```js
$("#candy input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
        $('#dd').removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $('#bbbbbb').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
        $('#dd').removeClass('selected');
    }
});


$('#bbbbbb').click(function () {
    var checked = $("#bbbbbb").is(':checked');
    $(".asdf").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', checked);
        if (checked) {
            $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
            $('#dd').removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
            $('#dd').removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
tr.selected {
    background-color: #FEF0BF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="candy" >
 <tr id="dd">
  <th><input type="checkbox" id="bbbbbb" /></th>
  <th width="20">a</th>
  <th width="20">b</th>
  <th width="20">c</th>
  <th width="20"">d</th>
  <th width="20">e</th>
  <th width="20">f</th>
  <th width="20">g</th>
  <th width="20">h</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf"  /></td>
  <td>v</td>
  <td>v</td>
  <td>v</td>
  <td>v</td>
  <td>v</td>
  <td>v</td>
  <td>v</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>                                 
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf"  /></td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td>e</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>                                  
 </tr>
    <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf"  /></td>
  <td>q</td>
  <td>q</td>
  <td>q</td>
  <td>q</td>
  <td>q</td>
  <td>q</td>
  <td>q</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>                                  
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to solve it? How to get the selected rows?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish here

Comment: totally there are three checkbox. The first checkbox to the left is should be enable to select the row by changing the background color to yellow. The 2 checkboc to the right side should NOT enable to change the background color. In other words, only one checkbox should be enabl to change the background color. Please inform me if you need more info.

Comment: So for the sake of this question you don't want the second checkboxes to do anything?

Comment: Both the second and the third checkbox shall not do anything

Comment: And just ps you want to make your jsfiddle link a link rather than a code block

Answer (score 1):

For your selector just select the specific class of the first text boxes rather then all of the text boxes  like this

```
$('#candy .asdf').on('change' function(){
     //your code
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To strengthen the answer by @Binvention you can use the exiting selector and add the class as well. This would be useful if the class `asdf` was used on other elements as well and not just the inputs

```
$("#candy input[type=checkbox].asdf").on("change", function () {
    ...
});
```

Additionally if the class was not present then you could select the *first* checkbox in the *first* row of *each* column using the following

```
$("#candy tr > td:first-of-type > input[type=checkbox]:first-of-type").on("change", function () {
    ...
});
```

Though I doubt this would be more efficient then just targeting the class directly, and also if the location of checkbox changed then this selector would break. I recommend using the class if you have it.

Comment: Technically for this specific setup this would do the exact same as mine it's just longer. If you had more inputs then just text boxes that used that class then using the full selector would be useful.

Comment: @Binvention Agreed. Yours is easier on the eyes and I would recommend using it over a more complex selector like the ones I have presented here (for this case). But for future searchers I wanted to add more options for completeness and show an example where the class could not be used directly due to other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you corectly, this will do. You select only checkbox with class 'asdf' and change background color of the row where that checkbox located.
Other two checkboxes in that row do nothing.

```js
$('.asdf').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).attr("checked") == 'checked')
        $(this).parent().parent().css('backgroundColor', '#ff0');
    else
        $(this).parent().parent().css('background', 'none');
});
```